# How can I remove pencil marks from a painted wall ...?

Tags: walls, paint, removal

... without damaging the wall.  My first inclination was to just use an eraser but I imagine this would remove much of the paint.

If this is the only way..., how do I repair the eraser mark?

Here is a pic of the pencil marks on a wall painted off white which obviously has some texture to it.

[image]

Comment: If your paint is worth a damn, an eraser will do the job just fine. Just erase the markings lightly and slowly. Don't rush it.

Comment: If the eraser does not work, then you get to re-paint...

Comment: Not all erasers were created alike.  They also tend to not age well, they harden over time.  Look for soft and fresh.

Comment: I also just remembered Art Gum and Kneaded erasers.  Check the art supplies rather than office supplies.

Comment: I've also had good luck with "magic eraser" which is more of a cleaning product than an art/office product, but worked surprisingly well on a lot of minor wall marks when clearing out a house for sale. For that matter, whatever is in most of those "cleaning/disinfecting wipe" products also works quite well, as does simply washing the wall.

Comment: I agree with ecnerwal I hav a 3 year old grandson that found some pencils & permanent markers and he created his masterpiece on our hallway. We used mr clean magic eraser and all the pencil marks are gone and almost all of the permanent marker so the magic erasers do work quite well.

Comment: Ecnerwal and Ed Beal are right - I have used Magic Erasers for marks of all sorts (incl. pencil). If you still need to get it off --- put a small dab of Vim right onto the eraser and it will come right off - leaving your paint intact.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just use an eraser as long as you use it gently. Even a simple pencil eraser can handle the problem, but you can use art gum erasers or suede stones as well. If you want to go a little further, baking soda or toothpaste dabbed onto the end of a soft cloth has also been known to work.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

I use lacquer thinner to remove pencil marks from bare wood, painted walls and the like. On painted walls, care must be used, a heavy, sustained concentration of lacquer thinner will remove the paint too. Use a saturated towel, not dripping, and wipe over the surface once, get a clean surface showing again and wipe the remaining mark. Typically you will see the wall color on the rag, that is normal, and why you don't want to be too aggressive with the thinner.